# Cant print out last element of array correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, inventory

I am using an array to store all gameObjects with the tag "ChoosenItems". If the layer picks up 8 items, it will print out all items selected in the console. When I pick up the final item, it prints out the image name of the first 7 and the last item remain "empty_item". It is adding all the elements to the array but the last element isn't the last item selected for some reason.

I tried delaying my function using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

```
    public class PickUpItem : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
    {
        public string DisplaySprite;
        public string DisplayImage;
        public static int counter;
        public static GameObject InventorySlots;
        public static GameObject[] PlayerItems = new GameObject[8];

        public void Interact(DisplayImage currentDisplay)
        {
            ItemPickUp();
        }

        void Start() { }
        void Update() { }

        public void ItemPickUp()
        {
            InventorySlots = GameObject.Find("Slots");
            int j;
            counter = 0;

            foreach (Transform slot in InventorySlots.transform)
            {
                if (slot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name == "empty_item")
                {
                    slot.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite =
                        Resources.Load<Sprite>("Inventory Items/" + DisplaySprite);
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                    break;
                }

                if (counter <= 7)
                {
                    counter++;

                    if (counter >= 7)
                    {
                        {
                            Debug.Log("You have choosen all your items.");

                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            Debug.Log("Waiting 5 second.");

                            PlayerItems = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ChoosenItem");

                            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                            {
                                Debug.LogFormat("Item[{0}] = {1}", j, PlayerItems[j].GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Item[0] = key_yellow
Item[1] = 2 spades
Item[2] = RocketSprite
Item[3] = color paper
Item[4] = 4 diamonds
Item[5] = CoinSprite
Item[6] = TruckChassisSprite
Item[7] = MagnetSprite
```

Actual Output is:

```
Item[0] = key_yellow
Item[1] = 2 spades
Item[2] = RocketSprite
Item[3] = color paper
Item[4] = 4 diamonds
Item[5] = CoinSprite
Item[6] = TruckChassisSprite
Item[7] = empty_item
```

Comment: It is difficult to see what is wrong in you code, because it is an extract of a larger code base which is not easy to understand in isolation. My best guess would be that changing `if (counter >= 7)` to `if (counter > 7)` would solve your problem. The code in the body of the second `if` will be executed already in the seventh iteration of the loop, because it happens *after* incrementing `counter`.

Comment: Can you show where/how you are assigning the tag `ChoosenItem` to `GameObject`s?

Comment: You are telling them at the 7th item their inv is full not 8..

Comment: I created a tag in the unity engine called "ChoosenItem" and attached it to each inventory slot item. It's the same as the "player" tag that you can use.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "ChosenItems"?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ixhFzDO3q7Am0mbVJlKU5Hrht52sZFO5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping through your code?  After you process your first item `counter` will be set to 1.  Continuing on, after you process your seventh item, `counter` will be set to 7 and the items will be printed out.

Try changing

`if (counter >= 7)`

to

`if (counter > 7)`

Comment: If I do that, the if statement will never run because the counter won't be more than 7.

Comment: Again, step through your code. You'll see that when you start processing your 8th item, the counter variable is 7.  You'll fall into the first if statement, increment the counter to 8, then fall into the second if statement.